# How to create RegEx table in Google Tag Manager that finds a word in the URL of ClickURL?

Tags: google-tag-manager, regex

How do I create RegEx table that find a word in the URL of ClickURL?

I want to that the RegEx table will check if the word "online" exists in the ClickURL - if so, the input will be "online".

Comment: It looks like [regex tables have output](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/the-regex-table-variable-in-google-tag-manager/)   What do you want the output to be when the input is "online"?

Comment: The output should be "אונליין" 
(online in Hebrew)

My goal is that every click on a link that contain "online" will send me back the text "אונליין"